# Save video in Photo Library Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, save, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to save a video in my Photo Library. To get started I tried to simply pick a video by using the UIImagePickerController and after picking it saving it again in the library using the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum. Doesn't make much sense but I try to understand how saving videos work.

The following code does not work, as it does not save the video:

```
@IBAction func ChooseVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL
    print(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL!.path))

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL!.path, self,  #selector(self.video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    })
}
```

I hope you can help me as I couldn't find much about saving videos.

Best regards,
MB

**Solution:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    // *** store the video URL returned by UIImagePickerController *** //
    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL

    // *** load video data from URL *** //
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL)

    // *** Get documents directory path *** //
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]

    // *** Append video file name *** //

    print(paths)
    let dataPath = paths.appending("/videoFileName.mp4")

    // *** Write video file data to path *** //
    videoData?.write(toFile: dataPath, atomically: false)

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath))
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject
            // fetchResult is your latest video PHAsset
            // To fetch latest image  replace .video with .image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Use following func to save video to documents directory**

  ```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
  {
      // *** store the video URL returned by UIImagePickerController *** //
      let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

      // *** load video data from URL *** //
      let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

      // *** Get documents directory path *** //
      let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]

      // *** Append video file name *** //
      let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/videoFileName.mp4")

      // *** Write video file data to path *** //
      videoData?.writeToFile(dataPath, atomically: false)
  }
  ```
- **now save this video in photo gellary**

  ```
  PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
      PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: Your document directory file)
  }) { saved, error in
      if saved {
          let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
          fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

          let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject
          // fetchResult is your latest video PHAsset
          // To fetch latest image  replace .video with .image
      }
  }
  ```

after it if you don't need then delete the image from document directory
, I hope it will work for you ...:)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. I had to make some slight changes as some errors occured which is why I updated my question with the final code. Have a great day!